# CSS :active in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, pseudo-class

I am using the `active` pseudo class for a `button` and it's not working in iOS only. Works on all desktop browsers and android browsers.

I have used the Safari debugging tools with an iOS device plugged in. If I leverage `Forced Pseudo-Classes` selecting the `Active` option, it works as expected. It just doesn't respond with touch.

Pretty Simple, on active it should turn red and move downward on the y-axis.

**HTML**

```
<button class="button">
 test
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 100px 100px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

.button:active {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/fzu93c7r/4/](http://JSFiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS is a bit strange on that. You can use `ontouchstart` as follows:

```
<button class="button" ontouchstart>test</button>
```

Or the pseudo `:target` (works for `<a>` tags)

```
.button:target { 
     background-color: red; box-shadow: 0 5px #666; transform: 
     translateY(4px); 
 }
```

Comment: `ontouchstart` worked. `:target` did not since it's not an `<a>`. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, not an `<a>`, good to know. I update the answer. Thanks for the info.